# Facebook approved App doesn't show up in App Center

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-center

My App was approved "Your App Detail page is live and approved. It is available in search and may show up in the App Center.", but it doesn't show up in App center. The rating is 4+ stars. Are there any requirements for App to show up in App Center, except approval?

Comment: Did your app ever appear in the App Center?  I am having the same problem and am looking for answers.  Thanks.